# Exception while processing task java.io.ioexception: can't write or read

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dependency-management

Hello I added a new dependency and I started getting the following error when I try to run the application:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/paularellano/Documents/Workbench/Android/Huddle/huddle_2.0 updt/Huddle_Android/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/Users/paularellano/.android/build-cache/d4e5659d4f4fc411f22ba3f779b09d40beccc03f/output/jars/libs/internal_impl-23.0.1.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [internal_impl-23.0.1.jar:android/support/v4/view/WindowInsetsCompat.class]))
```

I tried adding an exclude but I am not sure what I should exclude to remove this duplicate jars, any help would be appreciated it! Thank you in advance!

GRADLE:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'

    //expandable recycler view **RECENTLY ADDDED AND GIVES ERROR**
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'

    //Testing
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.4'

}
```

I also added this line on pro guard just incase but no luck:

```
-dontwarn com.bignerdranch.**
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview` library uses support library version `24.2.1`, whereas you also imported support lib version `23.0.1`.

Either upgrade your support libs version to `24.2.1` or exclude support lib dependency from `expandablerecyclerview` library.

```
compile('com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Note, this *may* break **expandablerecyclerview** library, because it was written and tested with a newer support lib version.

Comment: it worked! all I had to do was upgrade my libraries to the new versions and that did the trick, always the simple things solve the issues! Thank you again for your help!!